# Why polyfills is being called multiple times on page load?

Tags: polyfills, angular15, gtmetrix

Website in Angular 15, served with cloud function.

After an analysis using GTMetrix, I realized that polyfills is being called too many times. Does anyone have any idea what I might have done wrong? Or is this expected behavior?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Skkl2v4Lwlp-FtfugvAKCeOerzcLF1h4/view?usp=sharing